# Internal inherited generic property won't allow internal type

Tags: c#, generics, internal

I have a generic type with an internal property:

```
public abstract class MyBaseClass<T> 
    where T: IMyInterface 
{
    internal T MyProp { get; }
}
```

Then I have an internal implementation of `IMyInterface`:

```
public interface IMyInterface { ... }

internal class MyInternalClass: IMyInterface { ... }
```

Finally I have a public subclass:

```
public class MySubClass:
    MyBaseClass<MyInternalClass> 
{
}
```

This final class throws an error:

> Inconsistent accessibility: base class `MyBaseClass<MyInternalClass>` is less accessible than class `MySubClass`

Only both types are `public`, and the internal generic type is only visible internally.

Why is this?

It there a way around it (other than changing `MyInternalClass` to be `public`?)

Comment: I believe it's related to inability to set access modifier more public than parent's one.

Comment: @MaKCbIMKo yes, but the parent is `public`

Comment: It goes from `public abstract class MyBaseClass<T> where T : IMyInterface`. This row says that `T` could be only something `public`, because the class itself is `public`. You even can't write `public abstract class MyBaseClass<T> where T : MyInternalClass` by the same reason.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a direct way around it. To me it smells like a misuse of inheritance for code sharing but I can't know for sure.

Can you not put the internal stuff on an entirely internal helper object?

```
class InternalHelper<T> {
 internal T MyProp { get; }
}

public class MySubClass
{
 InternalHelper<MyInternalClass> helper;
}
```

Now there is no need to expose generics in the public API surface area anymore.

If you want to expose a property of the interface type you could add:

```
public IMyInterface MyProp => helper.MyProp;
```

Generally, internal elements should not be exposed on the public API surface ever. This includes base types and generic type arguments.